# MySQL function in column default value

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use function in column default value?

I want to do something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO
(
     col1 varchar(100),
     col2 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT SUBSTRING(col1,1,1)
);
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: When you add value in column col1 at that time add substring value to col2 by 1 character from existing variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

[Only static values are allowed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) and [times values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) like `current_timestamp` or `current_date`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a VIEW of your table that uses your function to create the value.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  Please add more details to your post, in case the link is ever broken.